# Trying to add quotes mark (" ") in the starting and end of string in java

Tags: java, string, ternary-operator

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
bw.append(disruptedName.toString());
```

This is my main string to append. So if disruptedName.toString() = Adam then it should display "Adam".
Also i need to do this with the help of a ternary operator. I tried below but of no use:

```
bw.append(disruptedName.toString().isEmpty() ? "" : " ".concat(disruptedName.toString()).concat(") "));
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use backslash key for escaping:

```
bw.append(disruptedName.toString().isEmpty() ? "" : "\"" + disruptedName.toString() + "\""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Following would fix your issue

You can use backslash `(\)`

`disruptedName.toString().isEmpty() ? "" : "\"".concat(disruptedName.toString().isEmpty()).concat("\"")`

You may refer [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_characters.htm) to learn about escape characters